# The proper way to overwrite the settings/environment of an otp application dependency

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I wrote a very simple OTP application A. The default settings for this application are set in the .app file thanks to erlang.mk.

I am now using my application A as a dependency in my new application B. This application requires different settings for A than the defaults.

What is the proper way for my application B to overwrite the environment of its dependency, application A ?

Few thoughts:

- Since A is required by B, A is started first, so application:set_env/3  won't cut it.
- If possible I would like to avoid messing with startup parameters such as -config or passing the environment directly in the startup command.

Answer (score 1):

What about splitting A into A1 and A2.

- A1 is the "configurationless" version of A,
- A2 depend on A1, and provides it the necessary environment to fulfill the same services as A.

Then B will do the same with A1, directly or through a 3rd app A3.

Comment: do you mean like changing my first application into a library ?

Comment: If it is feasible, yes.

Comment: it will work in my specific case since I wrote app A myself. I was hoping for something more generic that I could also use with 3rd party dependencies. Anyway since it does work in my case, if nobody show up with anything more generic, I will accept your answer.